# JS ignores setTimeOut in conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code in a `script` tag:

```
var ya = true
setInterval(function() {
    if($(document).scrollTop() >= 135){
        $('header').css({
            "height": 50,
            "position":"fixed",
            "width":"100%",
            "top":0,
            "z-index":10000
        });
        $('header nav').css({
            "margin-top":0
        });
        $('#social').css({
            "margin-top":0
        });
        $("body").css({
            "margin-top":135
        });
        $("#luis").css({
            "display":"none"
        });
        $('header').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
        ya = false;
    }else if(!ya){

        $('header').addClass('animated fadeOutUp');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('header').addClass('fadeInDown');
            $('header').css({
                "height": 135,
                "position":"static",
                "width":"100%",
                "top":0,
                "z-index":10000
            });
            $('header nav').css({
                "margin-top":44
            });
            $('#social').css({
                "margin-top":43
            });
            $("body").css({
                "margin-top":0
            });

            $("#luis").css({
                "display":"inline-block"
            });
            ya = true
        }, 400);


    }
}, 100);
```

Yes. I have jQuery, and when the code reaches the `if` the styles apply.

The problem is that the code in the `setTimeOut` doesn't work but the conditional is working well, because the code outside the `setTimeOut` works as expected... Even if I change the time in the `setInterval` to 10000 (because I tought that the problem was that it couldn't finish the process) it keeps not working.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't "ignore it". Thus, one of these two things are happening 1) the if condition branch is never executed, or 2) it does run, but the results / side-effects are misinterpreted or otherwise lost. Start from that. Since you claim #1 isn't the issue, focus on #2.

Comment: how about closing the two `ya = true` with a semicolon?

Comment: @Banana Doesn't make a difference. JavaScript has ASI.

Comment: Actually, ya gets "true", Because the code in the `else if` work...

Comment: i bet your code works fine, and you simply have a syntax error in either `/*...The actions here also work ...*/` or `/*But this doesn't*/` and it doesnt reach the setTimeout function. please post your full code so we can see what you did there

Comment: Ok :) There you go, Banana

Comment: Still not totally sure what you're up to here, but I took a stab at simplifying your code: https://gist.github.com/dancrew32/4ee773ce9fd91c4450fc should run faster and be easier to debug this `ya` thing you're working on.